# Best Way to Inject Hibernate Session by Spring 3

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I am not sure whats the best way to inject Hibernate's session instance to DAO classes using Spring3. I am not using Spring's Hibernate Template support for this so here is the code i have in the DAO class.

```
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
    this.sessionFactory=sessionFactory;
}


public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
    log.info("Returning a refrence to the session instance");
    if(sessionFactory==null){
         log.error("Not able to find any associated session");
         throw new RuntimeException("Not able to find any associated session");
    }
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

Below is the code for injecting session in to this method

```
<bean id="genericSessionFactory" class="HibernateSessionFactory"
        factory-method="getSessionfactory" scope="prototype/>
```

I am not sure if this is the best way to do SessionFactory injection since we don't want to use Spring Template for our project.
So any other suggestion for improvement will be much helpfull.

Comment: How are you configuring the `SessionFactory` itself?

Comment: By using Hibernate Standard way a HibernateUtil class reading various properties and cfg file from the classpath

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [Spring Reference suggests this usage](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-straight):

```
public class ProductDaoImpl implements ProductDao {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public Collection loadProductsByCategory(String category) {
        return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery(
                    "from test.Product product where product.category=?")
                .setParameter(0, category)
                .list();
    }
}
```

That way your classes don't have any dependencies to Spring, you just use plain Hibernate.

Comment: This is what i am doing i have a generic DAO class where i have all generic persistance methods and i am injecting Hibernate Session factory in the DAO class,but instead of using Spring Hibernate SessionFactory Util class i am using my own implimentation.So seems i am on the right track..

Comment: I don't like injecting SessionFactory, since it is a PITA to mock the Session and do assertions on it in a Unit Test. Isn't it possible to inject Session instead of SessionFactory?

Comment: @BastianVoigt that's a separate question. feel free to ask. but the short answer is: that would only be possible if your repository class has a scope other than singleton or if your session is a bean which is a scoped proxy. Both of those sound nasty to me

Comment: @BastianVoigt while I second that, I don't think JPA actually helps you here. You should have the exact same problem

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd Not quite true. With JPA you can inject EntityManager which is similar to Session. No need to directly work with EntityManagerFactory in your code.

Comment: @BastianVoigt yes, I am aware of that. But the Entitymanager then has to be a scoped proxy, as I wrote above. see the end of this section: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#orm-jpa-straight

Answer (score 23):

A combination of skaffman's post and Sean's plus the use of annotations.

Dao

```
@Respository("productDao")
public class ProductDaoImpl implements ProductDao {

    @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

            public Collection loadProductsByCategory(String category) {
                    return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                        .createQuery(
                            "from test.Product product where product.category=?")
                        .setParameter(0, category)
                        .list();
        }
}
```

xml

```
<beans>

  <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001"/>
    <property name="username" value="sa"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="mappingResources">
      <list>
        <value>product.hbm.xml</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <value>
        hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
      </value>
    </property>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: can you please post an equivalent java config

Answer (score 22):

You're over-complicating this.

Please do not use that awful `HibernateUtil` pattern that keeps popping up in the Hibernate documentation. Spring provides a much, much nicer way of configuring a Hibernate `SessionFactory` - the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` ([see docs for example usage](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-session-factory-setup)).

`LocalSessionFactoryBean` produces a `SessionFactory` object, which you can inject as a property into your DAO beans.

Spring is happy for you to not use `HibernateDaoSupport` and `HibernateTemplate` - there's a [section of the docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-straight) explaining how to do it nicely.

Comment: Thanks for the document pointer and i must say will use Spring's LocalSessionFactoryBean for handling Session factory creation and than will use my generic DAO pattern to use SessionFactory being created by LocalSessionFactoryBean

Answer (score 14):

The advisable way of using Hibernate is through JPA (hibernate-entitymanager):

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

and in the `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="yourUnitName" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> <!-- needs a data source bean -->
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="${hibernate.dialect}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>



<bean id="transactionManager" 
  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

And you'll need a `META-INF/persistence.xml`