# Quartz + Struts

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts, quartz-scheduler

I have a web application that using `Struts` + `Spring` + `Hibernate`. In this application I am getting data from a remote server in XML format, and write it to the database, when someone accesses the site, because of `StrutsActions`. Now I want to implement `Quartz` library, for writing to database does not depend on users, but I have no idea how to call an `Action` from `Quartz`.

*Thanks and sorry for my english.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<bean name="archiveTask" 
    class="com.yourcompany.ArchiveTriggerTask">
</bean>

<bean id="archiveJobDetail" 
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
     <property name="targetObject" ref="archiveTask" />
     <property name="targetMethod" value="execute" />
</bean>

<bean id="archiveCronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="archiveJobDetail" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 30 10-13 ? * WED,FRI" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
<property name="triggers">
    <list>
        <ref bean="archiveCronTrigger" />
    </list>
</property>
```

You need to adjust the cronExpression to your requirement.
Then create your class with execute method in it.

```
public class ArchiveTriggerTask   {
    public void execute()  {
            //insert your code here
    }
}
```

To adjust the cronExpression http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorial/TutorialLesson06.html

Comment: If I am trying to add HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response as method parameters, application doen's want to start, it shows me java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.deveto.struts.util.ArchiveTriggerTask.execute(), I need the request, to be able to call SpringService from it.

Comment: Since your ArchiveTriggerTask is bean, you can inject other beans to it. There you goes, your spring service beans :)

Comment: Ok, for example I have declared it in Spring configuration file, but how can I call it in ArchiveTriggerTask, via annotations?

Comment: I did it once, I don't remember it works or not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699381/best-way-to-inject-hibernate-session-by-spring-3/4699592#4699592