# For configuring DataSource where are we giving host name, username, password etc details

Tags: spring

For configuring DataSource where are we giving host name, username, password etc details?
What is LocalSessionFactoryBean? What are its uses? From where does the JndiObjectFactoryBean class get the database details? Can anybody explain in detail how does it work?
Any ideas, resources,sample code,links, highly appreciated. thanks in advance.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean>   
<property name="jndiName"> <value>java:comp/env/jdbc/trainingDatasource</value> </property>   
</bean>   
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework. orm.hibernate.LocalSessionFactoryBean"> <property name="dataSource"> <ref bean="dataSource"/> </property>   
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this links. 
1. [StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699381/best-way-to-inject-hibernate-session-by-spring-3)
2. [SpringByExample link](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-hibernate-xml-config.html)
3. [Blog link](http://snehaprashant.blogspot.in/2009/05/integrating-hibernate-with-spring.html)

LocalSessionFactoryBean: FactoryBean that creates a Hibernate SessionFactory. This is the usual way to set up a shared Hibernate SessionFactory in a Spring application context; the SessionFactory can then be passed to Hibernate-based DAOs via dependency injection.

Hope this will help you.