# Spring Hibernate-sessionfactory is null while trying to inject it in DAO

Tags: spring, hibernate, dependency-injection, spring-annotations

The session factory I have defined is `null` in DAO. Here goes my code:

```
@Repository
public class LinkDetailsDAO {

     private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

     @Autowired
     public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
         this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
     }

     Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

throws a `NullPointerException` when I am trying to create a session object.

My applicationContext:

```
  <!-- Load Hibernate related configuration -->
  <import resource="hibernate-context.xml"/>

 <context:annotation-config/>
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.Neuverd.*"/>
```

My hibernate-context:

```
 <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/config/testapp.properties" />

<!-- Enable annotation style of managing transactions -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> 

<!-- Declare the Hibernate SessionFactory for retrieving Hibernate sessions -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
 p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
 p:configLocation="/WEB-INF/config/hibernate.cfg.xml"
 p:packagesToScan="com.Neuverd"/>

 <!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities--> 
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
 destroy-method="close"
p:driverClassName="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}"
p:url="${app.jdbc.url}"
p:username="${app.jdbc.username}"
p:password="${app.jdbc.password}"
/>
```

and my hibernate config file

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- We're using MySQL database so the dialect needs to MySQL as well-->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
        <!-- Enable this to see the SQL statements in the logs-->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I have tried using the @Resource annotation too. but no luck. I am using Spring 3.1 and Hibernate 4.1.

The application throws a `BeanCreationException` for `LinkDetailsDAO` during start-up, caused due to the above-mentioned `NullPointerException`.

After the `sessionFactory` bean and `transactionManager` bean is created, when the container tries to create the `LinkDetailsDAO` bean, it fails. I don't understand why a `null` `sessionFactory` bean is created!!.  Tried a `sessionFactory` as mentioned in the [spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-session-factory-setup) doc. Not working.

Comment: Did you check the spring startup log?

Comment: Why are you not using HibernateDaoSupport?

Comment: @kurt: yes. The error is thrown when the applicationContext is loaded via ContextLoaderListener.

Comment: @saurabh: I went through couple of articles and decided not use it. You can check the answer by skaffman here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699381/best-way-to-inject-hibernate-session-by-spring-3

Comment: I'd check the log. Maybe SessionFactory is not starting properly. Look for the main reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You try to call `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` in the constructor. But the object has to be constructed first, before Spring can call the setter and inject the session factory. So obviously, at construction time, the session factory is null.

Even if the session factory was injected in the constructor and you asked for a session after, there wouldn't be any transactional context, and `getCurrentSession()` would throw an exception.

You should get a session from the factory only from inside the methods of the DAO. This is the way to get the current session, i.e. the session associated to the current transaction.

```
public void doSomething() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have a doubt. when i say @Autowired
 private SessionFactory sessionFactory; Isn't the bean injected during the construction of that DAO object (from my understanding the bean you define in the appcontext gets created first)?

Comment: No. The constructor is called first, and then the field is populated via reflection.

Comment: I am having similar problem. How is the sessionFactory being used in the constructor?