# Unable to retrieve the result set from database the second time i query it from my application

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller, caching

I am developing an application using Hibernate+Spring MVC. At the login page, I simply query a user table and validate if user is valid or not. It works smooth using my configuration of Spring and Hibernate. But the problem is once, I create a session factory, the next time when i try to validate. It doesn't fetch the user details. The code is running fine and neither any error is being thrown. I tried to uncheck second level cache too,but the problem still exists.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
<property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"></property>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE"></property>
<property name="username" value="testdata"></property>
<property name="password" value="testdata"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
<property name="packagesToScan" value="org.test.model"></property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
    </props>
</property>
</bean>
package org.test.dao.impl;

import javax.transaction.Transaction;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.test.dao.DaoMethods;
import org.test.model.Sla_Users;

@Repository
public class DaoMethodsImpl implements DaoMethods{

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

@Override
public int getUsersCount() {
    System.out.println("INSIDE REPO->GETUSERSCOUNT"+getSessionFactory());
    String sql = "select count(*) from Sla_Users";
    Query query = getSessionFactory().openSession().createQuery(sql);
    return ((Long) query.uniqueResult()).intValue();
}

@Override
public Sla_Users getUser(String username) {
    System.out.println("INSIDE REPO->GETUSERPASSWORD"+getSessionFactory());
    Session validateSession = this.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    System.out.println(validateSession);
    Sla_Users user = null;
    try
    {
        user= (Sla_Users) validateSession.get(Sla_Users.class, username);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("exception fetching user at login: "+ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        validateSession.close();
        this.getSessionFactory().close();
        System.out.println(validateSession+":"+getSessionFactory());
    }
    //Sla_Users user = (Sla_Users)this.getSessionFactory().openSession().get(Sla_Users.class, username);
    return user;
}
```

}

That is the xml, i used. I know that am missing out some basic part of hibernate,since its happening for all the values i retrieve in my application. For the first time the session factory is created, every time goes as planned but the next time i query the db ... booom....blows out of proportion. Saddest thing is, I won't even get an Exception. The code just stops running(waits for response from db).

Help me out guys.

Comment: Can you provide the code you use to request the database ? there is one thing awkward it's the presence of a jdbc template in your spring config.

Comment: @benzonico: Please can you check it now. I declared the template at one phase, but i didn't use it. Too bad, I just left it (it was invisible). Will be glad to take it down. But i don't think, that will cause any problem. Would it?

Comment: You are closing the session factory. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699381/best-way-to-inject-hibernate-session-by-spring-3

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the responses. I finally figured out the reason.

It was not due to the session. I was not returning the connection to the pool once i opened it, which was making the connection pool starve.

Once i added the following to hibernate properties in my spring xml, everything was working great.

```
<prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</prop>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that you are opening your session and not closing it while not using a connection pool. So when you do your second request you are waiting for the first session to be closed in order to open a new one. 
What you should do is use : `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` or close the session at the end of your requests using `session.close()`

Moreover you should not close the sessionFactory as mentioned in the comment made by @Jukka. Therefore you have to remove the line `this.getSessionFactory().close();`

Comment: hi benzonico, Thank you so much for answering. The problem is that, the application has queries that hit database often. I was thinking that some kind of caching in hibernate is avoiding the queries from hitting the db again and again. I will give u a small sample of problem: When I login, the console shows the log of retrieving the user details from db. The second time, it works fine and in the similar way. but the third time, it hits the db and console doesn't show anything & d application is just loading wit nothin 2 retrieve from db. I will try ur solution,but feel free to advice on dis