# Hibernate Session/Template returns null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session, properties

I'm pretty new to Spring, and I probably miss something obvious here. I'm working on a project that dates back to 2008 or so, which uses Spring (v4.2.5) and Hibernate (v3.5.6). I've copied some code from another project of around the same time-period, and currently try to access the Hibernate Session from that copied code.

Some things I've tried, which all gave back `null` for both the `HibernateTemplate` and `HibernateSession`:

1.

```
org.hibernate.Session session = org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils
  .getSession(getSessionFactory(), true);
// getSessionFactory comes from the Parent class 
//   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport
```

2.

```
org.hibernate.Session session = org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils
  .getSession(HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(), true);

// Where HibernateUtil is our own factory-class:
import java.io.PrintStream;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {
  private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
  }

  static {
    try {
      sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
      System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
      throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
  }
}
```

3.

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate = getHibernateTemplate();
org.hibernate.Session session = org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils
  .getSession(hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory(), true);
// getHibernateTemplate comes from the Parent class 
//   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport
```

4.

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate = getSpringHibernateTemplate();
org.hibernate.Session session = org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils
  .getSession(hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory(), true);

// Where getSpringHibernateTemplate is:
@InjectObject("spring:hibernateTemplate")
public abstract HibernateTemplate getSpringHibernateTemplate();

// With the following bean in our ourprojectname-general.xml:
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="mappingDirectoryLocations">
        <!-- Add all Hibernate mappings to the list below -->
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/hbm</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">spinoff/dao/ehcache.xml</prop>
            <!-- Determines the size of the JDBC fetch, that is the maximum number 
                 of rows that are exchanged between Hibernate and the database in one go. 
                 It's been increased to reduce overhead when searching for all entiteits -->
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">500</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">spinoff.objects.spatial.oracle.OracleSpatialDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size">25</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="use_sql_comments">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

5.

I've also tried [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4699592/1682559) with the same result:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No SessionFactory specified
>     at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
>     ...

---

On most other places in the code it's done like at *1*, and it was also done like this in the copied code in the other project.

My guess is that I need to `@InjectObject` or `@AutoWired` a getter for the Spring-bean of either the HibernateTemplate or Session, something like I've tried at *4*, but it remains returning `null`.

Could anyone point me to an answer? All I want is a Hibernate DB-Session in my class. If you need to see the code of any other .java or .xml files let me know.

Comment: I strongly hope you aren't going to do either of those things... Especially not option 2! You sholdn't be managing your session yourself, let spring do it. The only thing you should be doing is `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` and forget about `HibernateTemplate`. Also if you really want to use `HibernateTemplate` and a plain session use a `SessionCallback` and not obtain a session yourself (this would also mean you need to close it yourself and stop/start tx yourself, if you don't you will run out of database connections eventually!).

Comment: Also no idea what `@InjectObject` should be and/or how your daos are being configured/used. You posted a lot of code which isn't giving the needed insight. The `SessionFactory` and/or `HibernateTemplate` cannot be `null` because if it would you wouldn't even be able to start your application it would throw an exception. So I suspect you are doing things like `new WhateverYourDaoIsCalled()` instead of using a Spring managed and configured instance.

Comment: @M.Deinum Ah, your final sentence is indeed correct: "_So I suspect you are doing things like new WhateverYourDaoIsCalled() instead of using a Spring managed and configured instance._".. We have the code `Dao getDao(){ if(this.dao == null) this.dao = new Dao(); return this.dao; }`, which most likely creates the Dao because it's `null`. I will add this Dao as Spring-bean to the XML and see if it isn't null anymore. (And after that go read some more information about Spring in general.. >.>)

Comment: Only adding it is propably not going to help, you will have to inject it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as correctly pointed out by *@M.Deinum* in the comments, I was looking at my problem at the completely wrong spot. It turned out I forgot to copy a few String-beans from the other project's XML-files where I copied the java files from.
So, after copying and slightly modifying those beans it worked by just using `Session session = SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(getSessionFactory(), true);`

Here are the beans:

```
<bean id="ourDaoTarget" class="our.dao.OurDao">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="ourDao" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
  <property name="proxyInterfaces">
    <list>
      <value>plus.dao.IOurDao</value>
    </list>
  </property>
  <property name="target" ref="ourDaoTarget" />
  <property name="interceptorNames">
    <list>
      <value>hibernateInterceptor</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="messageProcessor" class="our.plus.MessageProcessor">
    <property name="ourDao" ref="ourDao" />
</bean>
```

And in the `MessageProcessor` class where the Dao was used I had to add a default constructor and getter & setter for the Dao.

Again thanks, *@M.Deinum*